# InvokationTargetException using javaFX with maven and IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm new to javaFX and maven and I've been trying to configure a new project using **IntelliJ** and **maven** and openjfx dependency. I followed the instructions [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij): javaFX and IntelliJ -> modular with maven and I chose **javafx-archetype-fxml** over **javafx-archetype-simple**. and everything works fine with the sample code auto-created by the IDE. but as soon as I try to add a `VBox` as my parent to the root I get exceptions. here is the code:

```
package afa;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        //scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary")); how auto-created code adds a Root to the scene
        VBox container = new VBox();
        scene.setRoot(container);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

and here is the exception when I try to run the code:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at afa/afa.App.start(App.java:24)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application afa.App
```

here is the pom.xml file I'm using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>afa</groupId>
    <artifactId>space-invaders</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>afa.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and finally here is the module-info.java file I'm using:

```
module afa {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens afa to javafx.fxml;

    exports afa;
}
```

interestingly if I created the project using **javafx-archetype-simple** artifact id, the current code would run without a problem but I couldn't add .fxml files. and I could not find any difference in both pom.xml s (pom.xml created by **javafx-archetype-simple** and the one created by **javafx-archetype-fxml**). 
I followed some of the similar questions asked here but I was not able to figure out whats wrong.
what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scene is not initialized according to code:

```
scene.setRoot(container);
```

So you've got NullPointerException

Comment: yes. that was a stupid mistake by me :). thanks